# How to add a page break in DataGrid after certain rows get printed

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, page-break

I have a DataGrid that displays a list of jobs. When I print this list, if it goes onto another page then some of lines get cut off. I want to add a page break after 15 lines. So once the DataGrid gets down to row 15, it will go to the next page to print.

```
 <asp:DataGrid  CssClass="tblResults" runat="server" ID="dgDetails" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblResultsHeader" />
                                <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" />
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Job">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"JobNo") %>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateColumn>
                                    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Date">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DeliverDateTime")%>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateColumn>
                                    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Collect From">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CollectionAddressInvoice")%>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateColumn>
                                    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="DeliverTo">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"DeliveryAddressInvoice") %>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

```
DataSet dsTable = null;
            dsTable = DataUtils.GetTableProperties(Company.Current.CompanyID, "InvoicePrint" + q.Job.JobScreen);
            if (dsTable.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                dsTable = DataUtils.GetTableProperties(Company.Current.CompanyID, "InvoicePrint");
            }
            if (dsTable.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataGrid dgDetails = new DataGrid();
                dgDetails.ID = "dgResults";
                dgDetails.Width = new Unit(dsTable.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Width"].ToString());
                dgDetails.BorderWidth = new Unit(dsTable.Tables[0].Rows[0]["BorderWidth"].ToString());

                switch (dsTable.Tables[0].Rows[0]["GridLines"].ToString().ToUpper())
                {
                    case "BOTH":
                        dgDetails.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
                        break;
                    case "HORIZONTAL":
                        dgDetails.GridLines = GridLines.Horizontal;
                        break;
                    case "NONE":
                        dgDetails.GridLines = GridLines.None;
                        break;
                    case "VERTICAL":
                        dgDetails.GridLines = GridLines.Vertical;
                        break;
                }
                dgDetails.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                dgDetails.ShowFooter = false;
                dgDetails.DataKeyField = dsTable.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DataKeyField"].ToString();
                dgDetails.CssClass = "tblResults";

                dgDetails.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "tblResultsHeader";
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Company.Current.Theme))
                {
                    dgDetails.HeaderStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(Company.Current.TextColor);
                    dgDetails.HeaderStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(Company.Current.Theme);
                }
                dgDetails.AlternatingItemStyle.CssClass = "ResultsStyleAlt";
                dgDetails.ItemStyle.CssClass = "ResultsStyle";
                dgDetails.AllowSorting = false;
                dgDetails.AllowPaging = false;

                foreach (DataRow dr in dsTable.Tables[1].Rows)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(dr["ShowInTableOnly"]) || !Convert.ToBoolean(dr["ShowInPopUpOnly"]))
                    {
                        dgDetails.Columns.Add(CreateBoundColumn(dr));                        
                    }
                }
                List<InvoicePrint> invItems = InvoicePrint.GetInvoiceItems(Company.Current.CompanyID, int.Parse(q.InvoiceNo), OrderByPoNum);

                dgDetails.ItemDataBound += new DataGridItemEventHandler(dgDetails_Bind);
                dgDetails.DataSource = invItems;
                dgDetails.DataBind();
```

But where do I put the page break?

Answer (score 0):

You can check page index and set row style as *"page-break-after"*, it will help you to break page after some records get printed
see below code on print button

```
 GridView1.UseAccessibleHeader = true;

GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;

GridView1.FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;

GridView1.Attributes["style"] = "border-collapse:separate";

foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)

{

    if (row.RowIndex % 10 == 0 && row.RowIndex != 0)

    {

        row.Attributes["style"] = "page-break-after:always;";

    }

}

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

string gridHTML = sw.ToString().Replace("\"", "'").Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");

sb.Append("window.onload = new function(){");

sb.Append("var printWin = window.open('', '', 'left=0");

sb.Append(",top=0,width=1000,height=600,status=0');");

sb.Append("printWin.document.write(\"");

string style = "<style type = 'text/css'>thead {display:table-header-group;} tfoot{display:table-footer-group;}</style>";

sb.Append(style + gridHTML);

sb.Append("\");");

sb.Append("printWin.document.close();");

sb.Append("printWin.focus();");

sb.Append("printWin.print();");

sb.Append("printWin.close();");

sb.Append("};");

sb.Append("</script>");

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GridPrint", sb.ToString());

GridView1.DataBind();
```

hope it helps

Comment: thanks for the answer but I am using a DataGrid not a GridView